# Meteor - Where to put calculating methods properly

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm reading and watching Tutorials about Meteor since 1-2 Weeks. I've learned about how to structure a meteor app regarding server and client side code, accounts, security etc.
What i could not figure out:
Where do i put the calculation logic properly?

For example:
A user puts data in a form and the data is saved in the database. Depending on this input data i want to do several calculations by putting the data through lets say a chaining of around 20 Methods, and finally display some results.

At the moment i have all of these Methods inside the file where the Template.displayResults.helper is.
When i put them in another file they don't get recognized, i think because of the wrapper Meteor puts around.

---

**Example:** I have a collection of DIY projects and each of the projects has a field with an array of utilities that are neccessary for the project.

```
Projects = new Mongo.Collection('projects');

   /* 
   exampleProject = { 
        "name": "Kitchen table",
        "utilities": ["Hammer", "Glue"]
   }
   */
```

I want to display all possible DIY projects depending on the utilities the user has checked.

The UI has a group of checkboxes via the user can select a bunch of utilities he wants to use.
These values are saved in a collection.

```
Utilities = new Mongo.Collection('utilities');

    /* 
    exampleUtility = {
        "name": "Hammer",
        "checked": true
    }
    */
```

Then i want to calculate the possible Projects...

```
Template.displayResults.helpers({

projectsPossible: function () {
        var utilitiesCheckedDB = Utilities.find({
            checked: true
        }).fetch();
        var projectsAll = Projects.find().fetch();
        return projectsPossible(utilitiesCheckedDB, projectsAll);
    }
});

// Returns an array of all possible projects depending on the selected utilities
function projectsPossible(utilitiesCheckedDB, projectsAll) {
    var result = [];
    _.each(projectsAll, function (project) {
        if (project.utilities.length === _.intersection(project.utilities, checkedCheckboxesList(utilitiesCheckedDB)).length) {
        result.push(project);
    }
});
return result;
}

// Returns an array of all checked utilities in the current checkbox database
function checkedCheckboxesList(checkedCheckboxesDB) {
    var result = [];
    _.each(checkedCheckboxesDB, function (checkbox) {
        result.push(checkbox.name);
    });
    return result;
}
```

The question is: There are more methods like "projectsPossible" and "checkedCheckboxesList". Where do i put these methods to get a good structure?

Thanks in advance!
Vin

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem (or at least add code to your question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to register global helpers, just use [`Template.registerHelper(name, function)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper), for instance:

```
Template.registerHelper('projectsPossible', function() {
    var utilitiesCheckedDB = Utilities.find({
        checked: true
    }).fetch();
    var projectsAll = Projects.find().fetch();
    return projectsPossible(utilitiesCheckedDB, projectsAll);
});
```

If you want to make the functions `projectsPossible(utilitiesCheckedDB, projectsAll)` or `checkedCheckboxesList(checkedCheckboxesDB)` accessible from other (client) files, you can make them global. For example:

```
projectsPossible = function(utilitiesCheckedDB, projectsAll) {
    var result = [];
    _.each(projectsAll, function(project) {
        if (project.utilities.length === _.intersection(project.utilities, checkedCheckboxesList(utilitiesCheckedDB)).length) {
            result.push(project);
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make model classes, using the `transform` option for collections.  For an ES5 example, see the docs:  http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection

Also, you have to make that model class or function global by not using `var`.

```
(function() {
  foo = function foo() {
    alert("fooh") 
  }
})()
```

In the above example, without `foo =`, the `foo` function would only be visible inside its own file because of the wrapper.